# Find The Number of Trailing Zeroes

Tags: number-theory, logarithms

I have 4 Number `A,B,C,D`  I don't know these Number but i know the value of `Log Multiplication` of these.
I have to find the Number of trailing Zeroes in Multiplication of these Numbers.
For Ex

```
Let's  Assume A=10,B=11,C=12,D=13
There Log Multiplication value = log(A)+log(B)+log(C)+log(D) = 4.2345
```

How to i find the Number of trailing Zeroes in Multiplication of A,B,C,D.
In above case = Answer is 1 (17160)

```
The value can be very large also so it's not possible to directly calculate it like this 1434221.2232
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly calculate the product $ABCD$ without knowing the numbers $A,B,C,D$ individually:

$$
\begin{align}
ABCD &= 10^{\log(A)}\cdot 10^{\log(B)}\cdot 10^{\log(C)}\cdot 10^{\log(D)} \\
&= 10^{\log(A) + \log(B) + \log(C) + \log(D)} \\
&= 10^{4.2345} \\
& \approx 17160 \\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: The value can be very large also so it's not possible to directly calculate it like this 1221.2232

Comment: Well, there's no better way to do it then?

Comment: That is not strictly a mathematical problem, but one with limited datatypes of your computer/programming language I suppose. Note however that if the number 17160 increases, the required precision of the number 4.2345 increases as well. So if your 32/64-bit integer type ("int"/"long") does not suffice for $ABCD$, then a 32/64-bit floating point type ("float"/"double") probably won't suffice for $log(ABCD)$

Comment: @Simon: You got a bit of a chuckle from me with "if the number $17160$ increases"...

Answer (score 0):

Let
$$\log_{10}(ABCD)=x.a_1a_2a_3\cdots$$

Then, $x+1$ gives the number of digits in $ABCD$ before the decimal point in the decimal system. A negative value gives the number of leading zeroes after the decimal point.

After this, calculate $10^{0.a_1a_2a_3\cdots}$ upto an adequate precision to cover all the digits before the decimal point. It can be checked whether the precision is adequate by checking that adding a digit after the decimal point has no effect on any digits before the decimal point in the result.

Note that however large the number may be, it is always true that $|10^{0.a_1a_2a_3\cdots}|<10$.